# Транспонирование квадратной матрицы по диагонали

Tags: python, матрицы

Пытаюсь транспонировать квадратную матрицу по основной диагонали. Сайт Acmp не принимает код, может я условие неверно понимаю?

https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=1&id_section=8&id_topic=120&id_problem=742

```
import random

N = int(input())

b =[[random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(N)] for e in range(N)]

a = np.transpose(b)

for e in b:

    print(e)

print(a)
```

#второе решение

```
n = int(input())

b = np.random.randint(0,9, size=(n,n))

a = b.transpose()

print(b)

print(a)
```

Я так понимаю, там нужно без numpy делать. Подскажите, запутался конкретно.
Еще одно сделал решение. Не подходит

```
n = 3

matrix = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

trans_matrix = []

for i in range(n):

    trans_matrix.append([0] * n)

for i in range(n):

    for j in range(n):

        trans_matrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j]

for i in range(len(trans_matrix)):

    print(*trans_matrix[i])
```

Comment: А у вас формат вывода совпадает с требуемым?

Comment: Да и там работа с текстовыми файлами же, а не с консолью

Comment: Я просто на этом сайте сдавал уже работы и принимало без работы с файлами, дело не в этом, там везде пишут в условии input файл, я это понимаю, как данные которые будут задействованы в исполнении программы.

А вывод совпадает в точь в точь, пробелов лишних нет. В последнем решении точно. В остальных у меня матрица не разархивирована, но на самом сайте я и так и так проверял

Comment: Можете также попробовать такое решение `trans_matrix = list(zip(*matrix))`, но в целом на сайте куча ответов на этот вопрос.

Comment: Я думаю последнее решение более верное, и trans_matrix = list(zip(*matrix)) по итогу приводит к такому же выводу, как в моем последнем решении

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это. Можете изменить формат генерации и вывода, важна только функция transpose.

```py
import random

def print_matrix(matrix):
    for _ in matrix:
        print(_)
    print()

def transpose(arr):
    return [[arr[j][i] for j in range(len(arr))] for i in range(len(arr[0]))]

size = int(input())
arr = [[random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(size)] for e in range(size)]
print_matrix(arr)
arr = transpose(arr)
print_matrix(arr)
```

Используйте input для ввода из stdin:

```
size = int(input())
arr = [input().split() for _ in range(size)]
arr = transpose(arr)
for _ in arr:
    print(' '.join(_))
```

Comment: Вроде с рандомом не катит, много у кого спрашивал,у меня несколько решений с рандомом, которые выполняют функцию свою. Но на сайте выдает runtime error,как я понял ошибка связана с теми библиотеками, с которыми я не должен был работать. И саму технологию я понимаю, строки меняются на столбцы и наоборот

Comment: На сайте сказано про входной и выходной файлы. Может попытаться функцией open для открытия файла? Или имеются в виду входные-выходные потоки. Если речь про потоки, то нужно input-ом по очереди считать строки массива

Comment: Да, определенно нужно брать массив из stdin. Первой строкой считайте размер массива, а затем n раз считайте строку

Comment: Что-то `transpose(arr)` не так у Вас работает. Выдает исходный список. Вы похоже два раза транспонируете.

Comment: Ну не знаю, что у вас там не работает, честно не знаю
5
[6, 3, 8, 8, 6]
[5, 0, 6, 2, 1]
[7, 7, 6, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 9, 0, 10]
[6, 5, 3, 9, 9]

[6, 5, 7, 6, 6]
[3, 0, 7, 7, 5]
[8, 6, 6, 9, 3]
[8, 2, 4, 0, 9]
[6, 1, 5, 10, 9]

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить не о конкретной реализации, а об алгоритме транспонирования, то он заключается в смене местами индексов массива.
Например, если мы перебираем массив переменными i и вложенно j, то должно стать наоборот - первый индекс j, а подиндекс - i.
Как правильно отметил Mbo - проверьте формат вывода, возможно дело именно в нем

Comment: стоил внести это как дополнение в уже написанный вами ответ.

Comment: Ок, я недавно зарегистрировался. Не знал о том, что ответ лучше один